# When arriving at Stansted, does Eurowings exit passengers via the rear stairs?

Tags: airports, airlines, seating

When arriving at Stansted airport, does Eurowings (formerly Germanwings) flights  exit passengers via the back stairs of the aircraft?

Since they allow seat selection, I'm wondering if I should choose a back seat or a more central one (i.e., just behind the emergency exit), in order to maximise my chances of catching an earlier train from the airport.

Comment: How would exiting from the back stairs of the aircraft help you catch an earlier train?

Comment: @RobertColumbia if they exit from the rear stairs, and he's sitting next to the exit, he can get out earlier (instead of waiting for the queue at the front of the plane) and when you have a tight connection, minutes count! I've totally done that myself as well.

Comment: When exiting from stairs passengers are often bussed, so in that case it wouldn't matter. It only makes a difference when you get to walk to the terminal, so that should be taken into account as well.

Comment: Buses aren't used at Stansted (at least I've never seen any). Getting out of the plane earlier can lead to huge gains at Stansted for non-EU passengers on flights from Schengen, due to being at the front of the immigration queue.

Comment: Even on airports where buses are used it can make a difference, if you can get in the earlier bus you can arrive minutes before those who use the later bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've now completed the Eurowings flight to Stansted and this was my experience:

The rear door was never opened; we disembarked through the front.